# unnecessary second page in sale report odoo 10

Tags: reporting, qweb, odoo-10

I have problem in my custom sale report in Odoo 10.
I've made three possible sizes for product pictures.(small, medium and large). When i put for example 9 products in a quotation with medium size picture it printed out in 2 pages and this is quite good. When i change the size of the picture to small all my data are printed out in one page but the second page is still is printing empty just with the header and the footer.

Can someone tell me how to fix this problem.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust your page size under settings-->Technical-->reports-->paper format --> select the paper format and adjust the Top Margin(mm) and Bottom Margin(mm).